# How to prevent popups inside iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, popup, block

i have an iframe on my site and sometime the content of the iframe makes popup window to main, how can i block popup window with **javascript (Jquery) ?**

Comment: I'm not confident enough to post this as an answer, but maybe in the future you can [sandbox](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-iframe-element.html#attr-iframe-sandbox) it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't control the server that is serving the page in your iframe, you can't.  It's a security measure designed to prevent [XSS (cross site scripting) attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)

Comment: no, i want to block popup from iframe site (victom site), not allow popup.

Comment: that's exactly what he's saying michael. you can't do it.